# C# API bloc async upload without using await keyword in a scoped service object

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, asp.net-core-webapi

I don't want user to wait until the blob gets completely uploaded, hence I am not using `await` keyword in below async call, but I doubt the service object will get disposed as soon as API request is processed since the service is scoped to the API request lifetime.

But still when I run my code without using `await` keyword, the blob gets uploaded successfully.

Is it always going to work this way? if so, why won't the service object gets disposed, along with getting the upload async call unfinished/stopped?

Or shall I use another approach to make the API request faster, by saving the file in application root folder temporarily and running a background job to upload these files to blob storage?

**API:**

```
[HttpPost("upload")]
public void Upload(Model model)
{
   // Here I am not using await keyword, hence Upload API method is synchronous
   // though the inner definition UploadBlobAsync service method is async
   _blobService.UploadBlobAsync("uploads", model.name, GetBytes(model.file));  
}
```

**Service:**

```
public class BlobService : IBlobService
{
   public async Task UploadBlobAsync(string container, string blobName, byte[] data)
   {
      var blobContainerClient = this.blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(container);
      BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);
      await blobClient.UploadAsync(new BinaryData(data), true);
   }
}
```

**Startup:**

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(x => new BlobServiceClient(storageConnStr));
builder.Services.AddScoped<IBlobService, BlobService>();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it always going to work this way?

You can't depend on it. It might, or it might not. There is a somewhat common pattern in Microsoft's APIs where closing an underlying handle cancels all I/O on that handle; this pattern isn't used as much today, but it's entirely possible a future version of the Azure Storage client library may take that direction.

> if so, why won't the service object gets disposed, along with getting the upload async call unfinished/stopped?

It is getting disposed; it's just not cancelling that call. With this specific version of the library.

> Or shall I use another approach to make the API request faster, by saving the file in application root folder temporarily and running a background job to upload these files to blob storage?

Yes. This is one form of a basic distributed architecture, which is the proper solution for this problem. I have a [blog post series](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html) on the subject you may find helpful.

Comment: Thank you Sephen, I was thinking same for going with 2nd approach however object disposal was unclear to me, thanks for explaining it.